# Unsual value returned using AVCaptureSession

Tags: objective-c, ios, image-processing, avcapturesession, avcapture

I am using AVCapture Session to detect some images in realtime and match the image data through XML data in my app and SURF algorithm ( SURF code available open source).

Now my XML consists of Img Data ( floating point numbers representing image features) and imgid( integer values from 1 to 9 ).

Logic is that whenever i point my camera to the image , it should detect the rgb values and send it to the SURF algorithm where the rgb values of images are already manipulated using feature point data of XML. Match the features and return the corresponding img id ( between 1 to 9) of that particular image. Using that image id, a match id is returned. If match id is any positive value, the image is said to be matched if zero then no match.

Now i am getting image id like this AVCaptureConnection: 0x59f3da0

The avcapture session code is the same that is being used in technical q & A of Apple.

Comment: trying to figure out the structure of the code....